# Push image built with docker-compose to dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a golang script which interacts with postgres. Created a service in docker-compose.yml for both golang and postgre. When I run it locally  with "docker-compose up" it works perfect, but now I want to create one single image to push it to my dockerhub so it can be pulled and ran with just "docker run ". What is the correct way of doing it?

Image created by "docker-compose up --build" launches with no error with "docker run " but immediately stops.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6' 
services: 
  go: 
    container_name: backend 
    build: ./ 
    volumes: 
      - # some paths 
    command: go run ./src/main.go
    working_dir: $GOPATH/src/workflow/project 
    environment: #some env variables 
      ports: 
      - "80:80" 
  db: 
    image: postgres 
    environment: #some env variables 
    volumes: 
      - # some paths 
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/workflow/project 

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I am a newbie with docker so any comments on how to do things idiomatically are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose` does not combine docker images into one, it runs (with `up`) or builds then runs (with `up --build`) docker containers based on the images defined in the `yml` file.
More info are in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.

so, in your example, docker-compose will run two containers:
1 - based on the `go` configurations
2 - based on the `db` configurations

to see what containers are actually running, use the command:

```sh
docker ps -a
```

for more info see [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

It is always recommended to run each searvice on a separate container, but if you insist to make an image which has both `golang`and `postrges`, you can take a `postgres` base image and install `golang` on it, or the other way around, take `golang`based image and install `postgres` on it.

The installation steps can be done inside the `Dockerfile`, please refer to:
 - `postgres` official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cf9b6cdd64f8a81b1abf9e487886f47e4971abe2/11/Dockerfile)
 - `golang` official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/a9171b851ba926f2979e8c711d25faa025194def/1.12/stretch/Dockerfile)

combine them to get both.

**Edit:** *(digital ocean deployment)*

Well, if you copy every thing (docker images and the `yml` file) to your droplet, it should bring the application up and running similar to what happens when you do the same on your local machine.

An example can be found here: [How To Deploy a Go Web Application with Docker and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-go-web-application-with-docker-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

In production, usually for large scale/traffic applications, more advanced solutions are used such as:
- [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)
- [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)

For more info on Kubernetes on digital ocean, please refer to the [official docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/)

hope this helps you find your way.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. So if I want to deploy my program to a website on a digital ocean server and run it in docker a better way would be to build my images separately and run them one after another or transfer whole directory to the server and run just "docker-compose up"? How it should be done in real production?

Comment: @navigante Build your images separately and push each to docker hub. On your droplet, have the docker-compose.yaml file pull the image from your docker hub remote